# Calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, rather then between two vectors

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

**Preface.** Since I did not get any reply on Cross Validated, I write here my question as well, since, it might be more appropriate ([Calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, rather then between two vectors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/626928/calculate-the-cosine-similarity-between-two-probability-measures-rather-then-be)).

**Introduction.** The [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is often calculated among two vectors, i.e. $C_S(X,Y)$:
\begin{equation}
C_S(X,Y) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i,Y_i)}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}^{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i}^{2}}}
\end{equation}

**Question.** Would it make sense to calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, $P$ and $Q$, on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, i.e. $C_S(P,Q)$? If Yes, would it be sufficient to use the above mentioned equation for $C_S(X,Y)$ and maybe just writing something like $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$?

Comment: If you are looking at $\frac{E[XY]}{\sqrt{E[X^2]E[Y^2]}}$ then when $E[X]=0$ and $E[Y]=0$ this is correlation, while if they are not then it is affected by these expectations

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Henry. I do not understand what your are trying to say, in relationship to my question. Could you please elaborate a bit more your comment/message? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\text{Var}}$
$\newcommand{\Cov}{\text{Cov}}$

In order to make sense of cosine similarity, one generally wants an inner product, and I don't know what natural inner product you can put on the the space of signed measures in order to make this work.

Regarding your specific idea, as you have defined it, $P$ and $Q$ are measures on an abstract measure space $\Omega$, so even if you were to take $X\sim P$ and $Y\sim Q$ for random variables, since $X$ and $Y$ would be $\Omega$-valued functions, we would have no natural way to add them and multiply them.

You might try to rectify this by letting $\Omega=\mathbb R$, and then it makes sense to replace the bottom two factors in your formula with $\sigma_X=\sqrt{\Var(X)}$ and $\sigma_Y=\sqrt{\Var(Y)}$ but even then, if you are going to make sense of your formula (I assume where you wrote $(X_i,Y_i)$ you meant $X_i\cdot Y_i$), and obtain a single number for it, then you need something analogous to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_iY_i$, which likely means you want $\Cov(X,Y)$, which in turn means you need to know a joint distribution for $X$ and $Y$.

The problem becomes that for any given pair of probability distributions $P$ and $Q$, we cannot determine a joint distribution uniquely from the individual distributions - a different choice of $X$ and $Y$ might give us a different joint distribution, hence a different covariance.

Having said all of this, if you start with random variables themselves, rather than their distributions, then it absolutely *does* make sense to talk about cosine similarity for $X$ and $Y$, which is defined, as Henry mentioned in the comments, as the correlation coefficient $$\frac{\Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{\Var(X)\Var(Y)}}\text{.}$$

This is not simply analogous to cosine similarity, [it literally ***is*** cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products), in the geometry of the Hilbert space $$L^2(\Omega)/\{X\mid \Var(X)=0\},$$
obtained from taking finite variance random variables and quotienting out by the constant variables, i.e., those with $0$ variance.

Comment: Many thanks @M W, a very nice answer! :-)
Yes, I understood, also from the reply of Kakashi, that the issue would be related to the knowledge of a joint distribution. In other words, if I wanted to "extend" the cosine similarity $C_S(X,Y)$ between two random variable $X$ and $Y$, to a pair of probability distributions $P$ and $Q$ (of the two random variables $X$ and $Y$), i.e. $C_S(P,Q)$, I would need to know the joint distribution,  $\mathbb{P}_{X, Y}(E) = \mathbb{P}((X, Y) \in E)$ (as shown here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525334/joint-probability-measure/525342#525342) :-)

Comment: **Comment (part 1).** The reason of my question (and probably I should add it to the question) comes from the will to write a correct mathematical "unified" framework for the "measures of distributional divergences" that I am using, like the Wasserstein distance $W_1(P,Q)$, or the Jensen–Shannon divergence $d_{JS}(P,Q)$. The latter are indeed defined with probability measures (also called probability distributions by some authors).

Comment: **Comment (part 2)** Also, I wanted to use the cosine similarity as a measure of (dis)similarity among my distributions, but I had the doubt if all of this did make sense, i.e. if it was mathematically correct to use such different types of measures.
On top of that, what I am using are "relative frequency distributions" (histograms) that should represent samples of probability distributions, i.e. an estimate of the real probability distributions.

Comment: **Comment (part 3)** From this association, i.e. between "relative frequency distributions" and real (theoretical) probability distributions, I therefore thought to use the Wasserstein distance $W_1(P,Q)$ or the Jensen–Shannon divergence $d_{JS}(P,Q)$. About the cosine similarity, I thought that my pairs of "relative frequency distributions" that I wanted to compare, could be representative of the random variables $X$ and $Y$, and therefore that I could also use the cosine similarity.

Comment: **Comment (part 4)** Indeed, I could compare the values of $X$ and $Y$, bin-by-bin, i.e. the elements of $X$ and $Y$ as pairs $(X_i, Y_i)$ where $i$ would indicate the bin number of the "relative frequency distributions". I really hope I did not write total nonsense (I am not indeed a mathematician!), and I am just trying to be mathematically correct and still use a variety of measures to compare my "relative frequency distributions". In case, this comment should be posted somewhere else as a question, please let me know and I will delete from here. Again, many thanks for your clear answer!

Comment: @Ommo thanks for these comments.  You mentioned you are looking for a correct mathematical framework for "measures of distributional divergence" that you are using.  This might be a little outside of my area, but if you pose a new question explaining a bit more about what specific use case you have for these these measures (you mentioned you aren't a mathematician so I assume this is for some application), you might get some more informed answers from people who know.  If people understand what you are ultimately trying to do chances are better that someone can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot @M W! I will try to pose another question about this aspect, many thanks! :-)

Comment: I have written another question, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4774178/a-common-mathematical-framework-to-introduce-a-different-measures-of-distributi, thanks for the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't make sense to just write $C_S(P,Q) = C_S(X, Y)$ where $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$ because the value $C_S(X, Y)$ is not uniquely determined by $X \sim P$, $Y \sim Q$. The value is $0$ if $X$ and $Y$ is the trivial independent coupling ...

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kakashi!! Very kind! :-)