# A common mathematical framework to introduce different "measures of distributional divergences/similarity".

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**Introduction.**

1. I have two (actually more, but we can focus on two) "relative frequency distributions" and I represent them as histograms. Note: the "relative frequency distributions" should be an estimate of probability mass/density functions.
2. I am comparing the two "relative frequency distributions", among each other, through "measures of distributional divergences/similarity" (example of reference: [Cha, S. H. (2007). Comprehensive survey on distance/similarity measures between probability density functions. City, 1(2), 1](https://pdodds.w3.uvm.edu/research/papers/others/everything/cha2007a.pdf)).
3. I would like to use a variety of "measures of distributional divergence/similarity", such as the [1-Wasserstein distance](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf) $W_1$, the [Jensen-Shannon divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%E2%80%93Shannon_divergence) $d_{JS}$, the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) $C_{S}$, and the [distance correlation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.4101.pdf) $dCorr$, just to name some.
4. If possible, I would like to use the same "mathematical framework" to describe all my mentioned "measures", i.e. $W_1$, $d_{JS}$, $C_{S}$, $dCorr$. As far as I understood, the "mathematical framework" used to introduce $W_1$ and $d_{JS}$ is rooted in measure theory (for example, for $W_1$, please see [Optimal transport, old and new - | Cedric Villani](https://cedricvillani.org/sites/dev/files/old_images/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)) and I would like to use something similar (obviously, if it is mathematically correct for all the above mentioned "measures"). In that framework, $W_1$ and $d_{JS}$ are introduced to quantify the (dis)similarity/distance among "probability measures", $P$ and $Q$ (sometimes called "probability distributions" by some authors), on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, where $\Omega$ is a set, called the sample space, and $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. Therefore, people usually would write as follows: $W_1(P,Q)$ and $d_{JS}(P,Q)$.
5. On the other side, both $C_{S}$, $dCorr$ are defined for random variables $X$ and $Y$ (and not for probability distributions), which means that people would usually write these two measures as $C_{S}(X,Y)$, $dCorr(X,Y)$ ($X$ and $Y$ being used as inputs for the calculations). Also, if I understood correctly from other questions&answers (such as [Calculate the cosine similarity between two probability measures, rather then between two vectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4772917/calculate-the-cosine-similarity-between-two-probability-measures-rather-then-be/4773986?noredirect=1#comment10142937_4773986)), the simple observation/assumption that $X \sim P$ and $Y \sim Q$ would not lead to something like $C_{S}(P,Q)$, $dCorr(P,Q)$. And, probably, both cosine similarity and distance correlation as written as $C_{S}(P,Q)$, $dCorr(P,Q)$, would not make sense or would not be correct. However, since I have two "relative frequency distributions" to compare, I could compare them bin-by-bin, i.e. for each pair $(X_i,Y_i)$, where $i=1,2,...$ is an integer indicating the bin.

**Question.** Is there a way to introduce $C_{S}$ and $dCorr$ by using the same "mathematical framework" employed for both the Wasserstein distance and the Jensen-Shannon divergence, and quite likely rooted in measure theory?

**Note.** My desire would be to just introduce all of those "measures" in a simple way, like the following:

> Given two probability measures (or distributions) $P$ and $Q$ on a
> measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$, we can define and describe
> the following quantites:
>
> - $W_1(P,Q)$ is defined as...
> - $d_{JS}(P,Q)$ is defined as...
> - $C_{S}(P,Q)$ is defined as...
> - $dCorr(P,Q)$ is defined as...